# Not removing the right index Item from Listview

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-custom-view

I am creating a new `ListView` which will get its values from user input.This is working fine but I have a problem with removing item.

I have set a `OnItemLongClickListener` for this `ListView` so that I can get the right index for removing the item from the list. But it is removing the wrong index item. That means if I long click on the first item then I want to remove this item but every time it's removing the last item from the `Listview` (Toast is showing the right index).

Please see the source code for further details. See photos and source code.

```
package com.example.powerbase.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
Button button;
ListView listView;
TextView hTxt,pTxt;
BaseAdapter baseAdapter;
ArrayList<Item> inputValues;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    inputValues=new ArrayList<Item>();
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
    hTxt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hTxt);
    pTxt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pTxt);


    baseAdapter=new BaseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return inputValues.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return inputValues.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if (view==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view,null);


                TextView headerText=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hTxt);
                TextView pragraphText=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pTxt);


                headerText.setText(inputValues.get(i).getHeader());
                pragraphText.setText(inputValues.get(i).getPragraph());

            }
            return view;
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(baseAdapter);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String s=editText.getText().toString();
            Item item=new Item(s,s);
            inputValues.add(item);
            editText.setText("");
            baseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "New Item Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    inputValues.remove(i);
    baseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
    }
  });
  }}
```

Item.java file's source code below:

```
package com.example.powerbase.myapplication;

public class Item {
String header;
String pragraph;

public Item(String header, String pragraph){
    super();
    this.header=header;
    this.pragraph=pragraph;

}

public String getHeader() {
    return header;
}

public void setHeader(String header) {
    this.header = header;
}

public String getPragraph() {
    return pragraph;
}

public void setPragraph(String pragraph) {
    this.pragraph = pragraph;
}
}
```

Comment: The code you shared here looks good to me. So I think the error is elsewhere. If you like you can edit your question to add more code

Comment: The listview is not updated correctly. Try inside getView() of the adapter, move the close bracket of  if-condition to only include `LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view,null);`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for helping. Now this is working properly.